# Converting military time in Ruby

Tags: ruby, time, format

What is the easiest way to convert military (24 hour time) to HH:MM format in Ruby?

I have two 24 hour time values stored in a record and I want to display them in the view as something like "2:00 - 4:00"  when starting with two integer values, say 1400 and 1600.

My hack-y solution was to create a helper function:

```
    def format_time(time)
       if (time-1200 < 1000)
            if (time-1200 < 100)
                return time.to_s.insert(2, ":")
            else
                return (time-1200).to_s.insert(1, ":")
            end 
        else
            return (time-1200).to_s.insert(2, ":")              
        end         
    end
```

I'm not even sure that works all the time. I'm assuming there is a better way to do this.

UPDATE: I also need this to work on values that do not end in '00'. IE 1430 or 830.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could parse the string with `Time.strptime` to get a time object. This can be used to be printed with `Time.strftime`:

```
require 'time'

%w{1400 1600}.each{|t|
  p Time.strptime(t, '%H%M').strftime('%l:%M')
}
```

Advantage: Changes of input and output format are quite easy.

Alternative:

```
require 'date'  #load DateTime.strptime

%w{1400 1600}.each{|t|
  p DateTime.strptime(t, '%H%M').strftime('%l:%M')
}
```

I hope the solution with DateTime works also with ruby 1.8.

Update for `830`:
This solution will not work with `830` - `strptime` does not accpt `%l`. But `0830` would work fine. For this case you need an adapted solution:

```
require 'date'  #load DateTime

%w{1400 1600 830}.each{|t|
  t = '%04i' % t
  p DateTime.strptime(t, '%H%M').strftime('%l:%M')
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Got a "no method error" trying to call Time.strptime. Note: this project uses Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: I added a version with DateTime. I think, that will work also with ruby 1.8 (sorry, I can't test it myself)

Answer (score 2):

This will work, and it's easier o read

```
def fomat_time(time)
  time.to_s.sub(/^(\d{1,2})(\d{2})$/,'\1:\2')
end
```

Comment: Thanks, a regex make a lot of sense to use there.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def format_time(time)
  t = (time <= 1200)?time : time - 1200
  return (t.to_s.size == 3)?t.to_s.insert(1,":") : t.to_s.insert(2,":") 
end
```

That should work...

Answer (score 0):

If you always have the times in the form of integers like eg like 1600, 1630, 930 or 130, then this might be a solution:

```
require 'time'

def format_time(time)
  # normalize time
  time = time.to_s.rjust(4, '0') if time[0] !~ /[12]/
  time = time.to_s.ljust(4, '0') if time[0] =~ /[12]/

  Time.strptime(time, '%H%M').strftime('%l:%M').strip
end

time = 900
p format_time(time) # "9:00"

time = 1630
p format_time(time) # "4:30"

time = 930
p format_time(time) # "9:30"

time = 130
p format_time(time) # "1:30"
```

Comment: I want to use this method, but need it to work on times that don't end in 00.

Comment: So how do your times look like? Are they integers, etc?

Comment: see my updated answer (and pls test it throughly because the input times are quite unusual - you might also look into how they are constructed/where and in which form they come from, etc)